# SFSE Meetup at Dreamforce

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

Are there any plans to hold an SFSE meetup/event at DF18? We've managed this in previous years (although I don't believe one was held last year).

I attended the joint SFSE/dev group event at DF16 and enjoyed meeting others. It would be good to hold something similar (joint or SFSE only) for DF18. I'm happy to help organize if it makes sense to pull together a committee.

Comment: I would love to do such a thing, but as it stands, I probably won't make it this year because there's simply too much going on in my life. However, that's subject to change, so keep your fingers crossed.

Comment: I don't know if there is such a thing in the offing, but I'd like to come if there is!

Comment: I would definitely attend it If I manage to get my VISA sorted.

Comment: i'd love to attend

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update - 7th August**

Salesforce are unable to help us find a space, but they are offering us a budget of 500 USD to put towards food etc. which is great.

**Original Answer**

Hoping to secure a space through Salesforce themselves that may or may not come with catering. They've just closed the window for applications so hopefully I'll hear back in the coming weeks as to whether or not they'll be assisting us with a venue for a get together. If this falls through we should definitely try and find a space we can use, though they are getting harder and harder to come by at Dreamforce. More and more Salesforce partners have been sorting out their own spaces for hosting events and the like, so perhaps we could find a friendly company to host us if the Salesforce option falls through.

Comment: Hi Matt, do you think that the user groups budget could extend to an SFSE meetup? I know that we're not an official user group, but given the context of this community and the value that it provides, perhaps they could make an exception?

Comment: That's a good question.  It think the budgets need to be used for those regions, but we could ask, or just ask if we can register SFSE as the first world wide group :)

Comment: Just fired off an email, fingers crossed!

Comment: @EliotHarper I don't think its an issue of budget at this time. You may have missed the thread that I know you have access to. Several of us were the 1st to raise our hands and jump in with a request to have space for a SF.SE meetup at DF this year when the topic came up. Also, I can assure you that Salesforce is grateful that we're here and knows what a valuable asset SF.SE is to the community. :)

Comment: @glls Still waiting, hopefully won't be too much longer.

Answer (score 8):

If for whatever reason Salesforce is unable to secure a space at Dreamforce, I have requested that our shared office space in San Francisco be available for any date during the event. The office is near the embarcadero (1.5 miles away from Moscone Center)

[image]

Let me know if I should follow up on the request on my side.